# top bar ubuntu 20.04 power button is joined to Log out button

Tags: 20.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04.  in top bar power and Log out buttons are joined. to power off I have to click 2 buttons. but in ubuntu 18.04 I powered machine off with 1 button. How can I get back to ubuntu 18.04 top bar[image: here you can see image]